# Vlookup between two dataframes with duplicate values for the common column

Tags: python, merge, copy, vlookup

I am trying to perform a vlookup between two dataframes (df1, df2), the column present in both dfs is 'string'.
The problem is that in df1, where I should bring the values, the 'string'column has duplicates and I need to have them there so, don't want or need to remove them but for all of them I have to bring the value from df2.

My dfs looks like this

```
df1                                   df2                     expected result(keep df1)

string   col2                      `string        random          string         col2       
A                                      A         something         A             something
A                                      B         something         A             something
A                                      C         something         A             something
B                                                                  B             something
B                                                                  B             something
B                                                                  B             something
C                                                                  C             something
C                                                                  C             something
C                                                                  C             something
```

Is there a way of doing this?
many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([
['A', '-'],['A', '-'],['A', '-'],
['B', '-'],['B', '-'],['B', '-'],
['C', '-'],['C', '-'],['C', '-'],
], columns=['string', 'col2'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
['A', 'something'],
['B', 'something1'],
['C', 'something3'],
], columns=['string', 'random'])

print(df1, '\n\n',df2)
result_df = df1.set_index('string').join(df2.set_index('string'))
```